# How to input parameters into a script with questions with Python?

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to run a script with python. After the script runs, it asks some questions. Is there anyway to input the answer into the terminal with Python? Are there any libraries that could help me do this?

For example, a question could be:

```
Enter your choice (0-10): <Use Python to enter a value here.>
```

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're looking for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and maybe pexepect

Comment: @WayneWerner Thanks. I remembered seeing a similar question where someone recommended that library but I couldn't remember the name. Documentation for that is [here](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if you want, OP.

Comment: If the Python code must respond to different outputs from the script (adapt its responses to what the script says), then you need to look for `expect` or a Python implementation of `expect`.  If the inputs are fixed, simply pipe the output from Python into the script.

Answer (score 1):

something like this,

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('process argument')
child.expect ('Enter your choice.*: ')
child.sendline ('0')
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with the "os" library? I can run the script initially with os.system("scriptName -params"); Is there a way to inject text into the questions that come right after? I tried answering the question with os.system("answer to question"); but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible using OS library, however you can try using subprocess library and check the Popen method of it.  Just curious why you want to use OS library only when Pexpect is doing a perfect job for you?